# Smart way to compute Residual Sum of Squares (RSS) in Multiple Linear Regression

Tags: linear-algebra, regression

Is there any smarter way to compute Residual Sum of Squares(RSS) in Multiple Linear Regression other then fitting the model -> find coefficients -> find fitted values -> find residuals -> find norm of residuals... If I need only RSS and nothing else. For example, in best subset selection, we need to determine RSS of many reduced models..

Answer (score 0):

**[update]** *Upps, just saw your comment at @Nameless, that you have 10000 variables. So I think, that covariaton-approach is useless too. Should I delete the answer?* **[/update]**

One method needs only the inversion of the covariation matrix, don't know whether this is already smart enough?

Construct the datamatrix $D$ with the top row from the rowvector of $Y$-values, then the rowvectors of $X$-variables/values. If $X$ and $Y$-variables are not centered append one more row containing only 1. (If you have, say 3 $X$-variables and $n$ cases, you have then a $4 \times n$ or $ 5 \times n$ matrix).

Then compute the dotproduct of D with itself $C= D \cdot D^t$ and the inverse $B=C^{-1}$ Then take the reciprocal of the top-left entry of $B$, say $s = 1/B_{1,1}$ Then *s* is the sum-of-squares of the residuals.

Answer (score 0):

If we write in matrix form $$Y = X\beta + \epsilon$$ where

- $Y, \epsilon$ are $N \times 1$
- $X$ is $N \times k$
- $\beta$ is $k \times 1$

The RSS is defined as $$\text{RSS} = \frac{1}{N} \Vert Y - \hat{Y} \Vert^2 $$
where $$\hat{Y} = X \hat{\beta}$$
Let's say you've used OLS as the method to estimate your regressors, i.e.
$$\hat{\beta} = (X^T X)^{-1}X^T Y$$This means that 
$$\hat{Y} = X (X^T X)^{-1}X^T Y = P_XY$$where $P_X=X (X^T X)^{-1}X^T$is a projector matrix onto the span of the columns of $X$. Replacing this expression in the RSS gives
$$\text{RSS} = \frac{1}{N} \Vert Y - \hat{Y} \Vert^2 = \frac{1}{N} \Vert Y - P_XY \Vert^2 = \frac{1}{N} \Vert (I - P_X)Y \Vert^2 = \frac{1}{N} \Vert  P_X^{\perp}Y \Vert^2$$
where $P_X^{\perp} = I - P_X$ in the projector onto the null space of the space spanned by the columns of $X$. We can write 
$$RSS =  \frac{1}{N} Y^TP_X^{\perp}P_X^{\perp}Y  =  \frac{1}{N} Y^TP_X^{\perp}Y$$
Hence

> $$RSS = \frac{1}{N} Y^TP_X^{\perp}Y$$
>   where 
>   $$P_X^{\perp} = I - X(X^TX)^{-1}X^T$$

which is true since $P_X^{\perp}$ is idompontent. 
So the above equation suggests, that given $Y,X$ (which you already have), compute the RSS.